# paypal iOS sdk preapproval key

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk

is it possible to generate a preapproval key using paypal ios sdk ?
I tried with future payment but it doesn't seem to cover my case.

Otherwise do you know how to generate preapproval key using classic api with paypal mobile login (internet browser) ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the preapproval for adaptive payment? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/. If that's the case, then yeah, the iOS SDK doesn't support it because it falls into different set of API

Comment: PayPal has several adaptive payment SDK but not in Objective C as far as I'm concerned https://github.com/paypal?query=adaptive